# How to use cd command in su command?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, su, cd-command

In the below script the cases aserver and bserver work fine. But in case "cserver" above, after su - gsxuserp, I need to perform the following three options with the same user.

```
cd ..
cd random_directory
tail -f file_in_random_directory
```

I am not able to do this using -c option, since the connection just closes without executing anything. can someone please suggest a basic way to do this?

```
echo "Please type one of the following: aserver,bserver,cserver:" 
read input
echo "You entered: $input"
case "$input" in 
    "aserver")
        echo "Logging into a. Please enter the passwords when prompted"
        ssh -t user@something.com "ssh -t aserver "su - gsxp -c "sqlplus grep_ro/pwd"""
        ;;
    "bserver")
        echo "Logging into b. Please enter the passwords when prompted"
        ssh -t user@something.com "ssh -t bserver "su - gsxp -c "sqlplus grep_ro/pwd"""
        ;;
    "cserver")
        echo "Logging into c. Please enter the passwords when prompted"
        ssh -t user@something.com "ssh -t cserver "su - gsxuserp -c "cd """

        ;;
        *) 
        echo "Incorrect Option entered. Exiting the script"
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `su - gsxuserp -c "tail -f ../random_directory/file_in_random_directory"`?

Multiple `su`'s make no sense, because each starts a new session, carries out the single command, and then closes.  The subsequent ones don't remember which directory the previous ones were in, they inherit the directory of the calling script each time.

The full command would be (taking on-board the quoting comments in the other answer),

`ssh -t user@something.com ssh -t cserver 'su - gsxuserp -c \"tail -f ../random_directory/file_in_random_directory\"'`

Please note the use of single and double quotes (and the escaped double quotes), and not simply a series of double quotes.

Comment: Thanks EightBitTony :) I dont know why I didnt try that. But since cd doesn't work that way, are you sure tail -f will work ?        Also the file I want to do tail -f is inside a set of folders which are inside the parent directory of the folder I am currently in.    Since cd command did not work, I am highly sceptical about this working. Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks again.

Comment: Try it, it works, you're just passing the full path to the file, including `..` which means parent directory.  Your `cd` solution fails because when it runs the `tail`, the `tail` command is not in the directory in question.

Comment: The cd fails even without the tail. I have not used the tail in the script yet. Still it fails with cd itself.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by it fails.  `su` executes a single command.  The command you're asking it to execute is a `cd`.  So, it starts a new shell, executes the command, and then the shell closes.  At no point does the `cd` command change anything in your existing shell.  On what basis are you saying it fails?  Provide the output / evidence back in the original question (rather than here as a comment please).  Note you may also have problems due to the quoting issues described in Glenn's answer.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete info. Actually In case cserver it executes till the SU - gsxuserp and then closes the connection. It does not execute the command CD inside the - c of su - gsxuserp. It just gives..
Connection to cserver closed.
Connection to user@something closed.

Comment: You're executing `ssh` commands, `ssh` always closes the connection when the command finishes.  The `cd` command is being executed, and then, when it's done, `ssh` closes the session.  None of this changes my answer - try it before we go any further?

Comment: Hi @EightBitTony,    I tried the following: ssh -t user@something.com "ssh -t cserver "su - gsxuserp -c "tail -f /random_directory/file_in_random_directory"""    after the su - gsxuserp is executed, there is nothing on the screen. It looks like the screen is just hanging. I gave an echo "hi" in place of tail -f and still nothing. Any suggestions :( ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, more of a comment that needs extra formatting.

Your quoting is wrong: double quotes don't nest, they toggle:

```
ssh -t user@something.com "ssh -t bserver "su - gsxp -c "sqlplus grep_ro/pwd"""
# .... unquoted ..........^..quoted.......^..unquoted...^....quoted.........^^^
```

Your actual ssh command has these arguments:

```
ssh -t \
    user@something.com \
    "ssh -t bserver " \
    su  \
    -  \
    gsxp  \
    -c  \
    "sqlplus grep_ro/pwd"
```

This is a bit more sane:

```
ssh -t user@something.com ssh -t bserver "su - gsxp -c 'sqlplus grep_ro/pwd'"
```